# What is compatibility of JAVA 2d on Android

Tags: android, java-2d

I wanted to know the difference main difference between JAVA 2d and 2d drawing on Android. Can I port my Java 2D game to android without much changes ? or I need a lot of changes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Android uses OpenGL](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html) for performance 2D, and 3D graphics. As to how much work it would require to port your existing game, that will depend on lots of different factors. Without knowing more about the game you've created it would be impossible for us to answer that.

Comment: Its giving error in when in a object which require JPanel. is there anything similar to JPanel or how should i handle it ?

Comment: JPanel is from swing. Android has no support for Swing. You are going to have to rework any portion of your application that makes use of swing if you wish to use it on android.

Comment: Yes, Thanks a lot But which is the component which is similar to JPanel is it the Layoutmanager  ?

Comment: I only have a basic understanding of Swing so I cannot answer that for sure. But Android uses various types of Layouts instead of Panels. Read up on LinearLayout and RelativeLayout. Those are the containers you'll want to use to put all of your View widgets into